# How can I convert a date format in SQL?

Tags: sql, date, format, db2-400, ibm-data-studio

Some recently helped me to find a date with the command shown below, it returns the date in YYYY-MM-DD format, how can I convert that to YYYYMMDD so that I can use it to filter records in my where clause?

```
DATE(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)||'-'||MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)||'-1') - 1 MONTH
```

Comment: Please see [Why should I tag my RDBMS?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should tag with db2-400 when you ask questions about SQL running on OS400/IBMi/...

If you use a recent version of the OS you can get what you want with

```
dec(your_date)
```

And with a recent version of the OS with some recent TR installed you can get first day of preceding month as a decimal using :

```
dec(current date - (day(current date) - 1) day - 1 month)
```

or

```
date(trunc_timestamp(current date, 'MM') - 1 month)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what I needed. Also, thank you for the db2-400 tip, being somewhat new to this I never knew how to describe my environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
convert(varchar,[date_you_want_to_convert],112)
```

As shown in [microsoft sql docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Note, you should never use *varchar* without also specifying its (size)

Comment: I tried this: CONVERT(VARCHAR,(DATE(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)||'-'||MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)||'-1') - 1 MONTH), 112) and get the error: Column or global variable VARCHAR not found.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=3.69.56

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using IBM data studio SQL scripting to access data on an i-series, AS400.

Answer (score 0):

Bro I think you already have the correct format to use it into a query to filter records, see like I do a query using your date format.

[image]

This is my query

```
SELECT * FROM program_authorization_data WHERE dateCreate between '2022-01-13' AND '2022-01-15';
```

Comment: The field that I am comparing to is type S length 8,0 and the format is YYYYMMDD